# C# SendInput Alt/Ctrl/Shift Keys not getting Released

Tags: c#, keyboard, alt, sendinput

I am using the below code to pass special keys using `SendInput`. I am facing one strange issue. If user sends any of <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the key remains pressed e.g. if user passes <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, the code runs properly and action is completed successfully but <kbd>Alt</kbd> key remains pressed. I need to manually click <kbd>Alt</kbd> key after the operation is completed. Please let me know to handle the same in the code itself. Below is the code used to send special keys.

```
namespace RemoteDesktopSendKeys
{
class Program
{
       struct INPUT
    {
        public INPUTType type;
        public INPUTUnion Event;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    struct INPUTUnion
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public int dwFlags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort wVk;
        public ushort wScan;
        public KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public int uMsg;
        public short wParamL;
        public short wParamH;
    }

    enum INPUTType : uint
    {
        INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
    }

    [Flags]
    enum KEYEVENTF : uint
    {
        EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
        KEYUP = 0x0002,
        SCANCODE = 0x0008,
        UNICODE = 0x0004
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UInt32 SendInput(int numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, int sizeOfInputStructure);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetMessageExtraInfo();
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern uint MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
    private const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP1 = 0x0002;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int MapVirtualKey(int uCode, int uMapType);


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
          int[] keyboardStrokes = { (int)Keys.LMenu,(int)Keys.F4 };

        //int[] keyboardStrokes = { (int)Keys.ControlKey, (int)Keys.A };


        SendSpecialKeys("test", keyboardStrokes);

        //SendSpecialKeys("F5",keyboardStrokes);
    }

    private static void SendSpecialKeys(string text, int[] modifiers)
    {

        List<int> arrKeys = new List<int>();
        Keys key;

        if (modifiers != null && modifiers.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < modifiers.Length; i++)
            {
                arrKeys.Add(modifiers[i]);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            if (Enum.TryParse(text, out key))
                arrKeys.Add((int)key);
            else
                SendText(text);
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        int[] arrKeyStrokes = arrKeys.ToArray();
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[arrKeyStrokes.Length + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrKeyStrokes.Length; i++)
        {
            uint skey = MapVirtualKey((uint)arrKeyStrokes[i], (uint)0x0);
            inputs[i].type = INPUTType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inputs[i].Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
            inputs[i].Event.ki.wScan = (ushort)skey;
        }

        inputs[arrKeyStrokes.Length].type = INPUTType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        inputs[arrKeyStrokes.Length].Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
        inputs[arrKeyStrokes.Length].Event.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;

        SendInput(inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));

    }
    public static void SendText(string text)
    {
        List<INPUT> kbInput = new List<INPUT>();

        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            // Send a key down followed by key up.
            foreach (bool keyUp in new bool[] { false, true })
            {
                INPUT input = new INPUT
                {
                    type = INPUTType.INPUT_KEYBOARD,
                    Event = new INPUTUnion
                    {
                        // This will contain keyboard event information
                        ki = new KEYBDINPUT
                        {
                            wVk = 0,
                            wScan = c,
                            dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE | (keyUp ? KEYEVENTF.KEYUP : 0),
                            dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo(),
                        }
                    }
                };

                kbInput.Add(input);
            }
        }

        // Call SendInputWindows API to send input
        SendInput((int)kbInput.Count, kbInput.ToArray(), Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is just buggy code.  You don't set Event.ki.wScan for inputs[arrKeyStrokes.Length] and you only generate *one* KEYUP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be used to release particular key. Below is the sample code to release control key.

```
    uint ctrlkey = MapVirtualKey((uint)Keys.ControlKey, (uint)0x0);
                inputs[index].type = INPUTType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                inputs[index].Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.SCANCODE;
                inputs[index].Event.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
                inputs[index].Event.ki.wScan = (ushort)ctrlkey;
```

Need to make sure that proper key is released by passing index properly.